# google-chrome install/upgrading failed in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, upgrade, google-chrome

if i try to install, this shows up:

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installable
                        Depends: lib32stdc++6 (>= 4.6) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

if i try to upgrade, this happens:

```
sudo apt-get  upgrade google-chrome
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  google-chrome-stable
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

plz, help...

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal, copy and paste command, press enter, and if prompted enter your password.

`sudo apt-get install -f`

As for Google Chrome not installing, this is a problem that Google are aware of.

http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/stable-channel-update_15.html